# What kind of connector is this (WD Elements external HD opened)

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, connector

I opened my WD elements in the hope of finding a SATA disk with a removable SATA-USB adaptor, but unfortunately it appears the USB is soldered on the board, and there's no SATA connector. There is, however, a connector with 12 (6 pins x 2 rows) I can't recognize. There's also another connector on the left side, with only two pins. Does anybody know what it is[image]?

Comment: A related post: http://superuser.com/questions/337222/.

Answer (score 2):

Reminds me of jumper pins.  Seems like someone else asked your question and got a reasonable answer here:

http://community.wdc.com/t5/WD-Portable-Drives/Connect-by-non-USB/td-p/93926

Comment: I remember those good ol' Windows 98 times :P "Jumper  Pins" new generations don't know about them :D

Comment: Actually the link you posted, though relevant, doesn't answer the question. It claims that "the 12-pin header won't give you SATA access", but it doesn't provide any prooflink or explain what the function of this connector actually is (if it's a connector).