# "Extra" pins on WD MyPassport hard drive controller board

Tags: hard-drive, usb-3, controller, pin

I know that these pins are not "extra" but I'd like to know what they do... Are they jumpers like the old IDE hard drives had?

[image: WD My Passport USB 3.0 Drive]

The drive doesn't want to spin up anymore and I'd like to learn as much about it as I can.

**Edit:** [This topic](https://superuser.com/questions/337222/how-to-connect-western-digital-my-passport-using-other-means) references the same pins but never answers the question...

Image of the drive label:

[image: WD10TMVW]

Looks like a WD10TMVW.

Comment: They are most likely (primarily) for in-factory testing.  Exactly which model of drive is it?  Have you checked with Western Digital's support site for some technical documentation?

Comment: My relatives have the drive; let me get a photo of the label and post it.

Comment: They're definitely not an IDE interface, I can tell you that for sure -- that'd need 40 pins, not what looks to be a little over a dozen.

Comment: @AaronMiller - When he says IDE, he is referring to the master, master only, slave, cable select pins

Comment: @Keltari Those would only be present in conjunction with a pin header exposing an IDE interface, which this drive doesn't have.

Comment: If the drive won't spin up, your options reduce to shipping it off to some company that does clean-room recovery (and paying them a lot of money), or replacing it and restoring any data you care about from the backup one hopes you have. (Oh, I suppose you could try replacing the logic board, assuming you can find an exactly identical known good drive and that the HDA/logic board connectors make this possible, but your chances of getting away with that are slim at best.)

Comment: @AaronMiller The logic board replacement is the only option I seem to have at my disposal, but from the research I've done it appears that the board is inextricably tied to encoded sectors on the disk. I.E. I would have to extract the firmware from the bad board and flash it onto a new replacement board... Does that even seem correct?

Comment: @Shrout1 I have no relevant knowledge or experience, but it certainly seems plausible to me.